# Backup and Restore Site Collection from SharePoint Foundation 2013 to Server/Enterprise 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, backup, restore

I want to take a site collection (backup) from Foundation/Standard **2013** (ServicePack1) and restore this site collection to Server/Enterprise **2013** (ServicePack1).

The backup(.bak) file is created successfully.
But there's this message while trying to restore:

> (<)nativehr> 0x80070003 (<)/nativehr>(<)nativestack>(<)/nativestack>

Before the update to ServicePack1 it worked.

- ContentDB is SharePoint2013 ready
- I ran Configuration Wizard several times at both systems

Is there any solution OR is backup/restore from a site collection **not** possible with SP1 under different SharePointVersions (free vs. cost)?

SharePointVersions 15..something.. on both Systems

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The Problem might be the different Versions of SharePoint. They must be exactly the same!

To check the version of your SharePoint farm, navigate to

```
[CentralAdministration]/_admin/FarmServers.aspx
```

Or using PowerShell:

```
 (get-spfarm).buildversion
```

Comment: Can you please add some details about how to check this? It will make your answer much more helpful :)